# How to Get and Set Priority with XMPPHP

Tags: php, xmpp

I want my XMPPHP client to always get a copy of the messages that a specific user receives.  This requires:
- being able to detect all of their existing clients and their priorities
- being able to set the priority of XMPPHP to the same level as the highest priority set in another client.

Does anyone know how to do this with XMPPHP?  I tried changing line 190 in XMPPHP but it simply cannot get messages once my two GMail accounts chat back-and forth.

```
public function presence($status = null, $show = 'available', $to = null, $type='available', $priority=120) {
    if($type == 'available') $type = '';
        $to  = htmlspecialchars($to);
    $status = htmlspecialchars($status);
    if($show == 'unavailable') $type = 'unavailable';
            $out = "<presence";
    if($to) $out .= " to=\"$to\"";
    if($type) $out .= " type='$type'";
        if($show == 'available' and !$status) {
        $out .= "/>";
    } else {
        $out .= ">";
        if($show != 'available') $out .= "<show>$show</show>";
        if($status) $out .= "<status>$status</status>";
    if($priority) $out .= "<priority>$priority</priority>";
    $out .= "</presence>";
    }

$this->send($out);
```

}

This method is called with the following code:

```
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('talk.google.com', 5222, 'aaaaa@gmail.com', 'bbbb', 'xmpphp', 'gmail.com', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_INFO);
$conn->autoSubscribe(true);
$conn->connect();
$conn->getRoster();
$conn->presence($status="Active");
```

Comment: could you update the question to reflect the full code of this public class method, the function arguments dont really give allot to go by...

Comment: OK, so you are setting the priority by default to 120. I wouldn't change the class methods argument like this. How are you calling this class method? Show us that code.